Fetching multiple channel Id's using an array of channel names with youtube api v3
I am trying to fetch multiple channel id's using a array of different channel names in order to use 100 search quota units for a max of 50 channel names and 1 unit per channel id fetched instead of a 100 search quota units per channel name. in my research I've had mixed results on if it is possible or not. I am trying to optimise my 10,000 unit quota as much as possible. the code below works but it use 100 search units per channel name and 1 unit per id fetched.
 POST http://localhost:4000/api/youtube/fetch-multiple-channels ) {
  "channelNames": [ "MrBeast", "Sidemen", "mkbhd" ]
}

const fetchChannelIds = async (channelNames) => {
  const channelIds = {};

  for (const name of channelNames) {
    // Encode the channel name to ensure it's URL-safe
    const encodedName = encodeURIComponent(name);
    // Fetch channels that exactly match the query
    const searchResponse = await axios.get(`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&type=channel&q=${encodedName}&maxResults=5&key=${API_KEY}`);
    await updateQuota('search_channel', 1);

    console.log('Search response:', JSON.stringify(searchResponse.data, null, 2));

    if (!searchResponse.data.items) {
      throw new Error(`No channel data found for channel: ${name}`);
    }

    // Find the exact channel by comparing the channel title and description (which may contain the custom URL)
    const exactChannel = searchResponse.data.items.find(item => {
      const titleMatch = item.snippet.title.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase();
      const descriptionMatch = item.snippet.description.toLowerCase().includes(name.toLowerCase());
      return titleMatch || descriptionMatch;
    });

    if (exactChannel) {
      channelIds[name.toLowerCase()] = exactChannel.id.channelId;
    }
  }

  return channelIds;
};


Does this answer your question? I can't get channel id using YouTube Data API v3
